# How to search the tracks of a specific user with SoundCloud API?

Tags: soundcloud

I am a SoundCloud Pro Unlimited user. I am working on an App that uses SoundCloud API. it needs a search functionality to allow users search my tracks. I tries this:
`https://api.soundcloud.com/users/{id}/tracks?q=hello&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx`
but the `q` param seems to be ignored in this case.

It's unfortunate that SoundCloud has no official support for developers.